# NullPointerException when packaging optaplanner into a single uber-jar

Tags: java, maven, drools, maven-assembly-plugin, optaplanner

Please point me to the problem or give some advice how I could investigate the problem further!

I am using optaplanner v6.4.x. I have created a java project that contains only the classes necessary to run the minimal NQueens example https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/6.4.x/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nqueens/app/NQueensHelloWorld.java. Here is the output of the main method:

```
Solved 8 queens:
 _ _ _ _ Q _ _ _
 _ Q _ _ _ _ _ _
 _ _ _ Q _ _ _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ Q _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ Q
 _ _ Q _ _ _ _ _
 Q _ _ _ _ _ _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ _ Q _
```

I am using the maven-assembly-plugin to build a uber-jar that packages the application and all of is dependencies into a single executable jar. Below the relevant part of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.app.NQueensHelloWorld</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can build the jar as follows:

```
$ mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

which creates a nqueens.jar in the `target` directory. When I launch the jar

```
$ java -jar target/nqueens.jar
```

I receive the following NullPointerException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PackageBuildContext.init(PackageBuildContext.java:104)
>       at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.(RuleBuildContext.java:80)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRuleBuilderContext(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1804)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.preProcessRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1125)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1106)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileAllRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:989)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:260)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:121)
>     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105)
>     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:243)
>     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64)
>     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230)
>     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:198)
>     at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:447)
>     at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:298)
>     at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:230)
>     at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:233)
>     at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:52)
>     at org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.app.NQueensHelloWorld.main(NQueensHelloWorld.java:33)

Comment: Can you reproduce with `7.0.0.Final`? Drools should have much better error message than this and might it already has in a new version (if it doesn't, we can create an issue).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet The NQuees example from version 7.0.0.Final works and can be assembled into a single jar and executed. No problems there.